# Blazor ProtectedSessionStorage doesn't work

Tags: c#, session, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I try to implement ProtectedSessionStorage in some Blazor components (.NetCore 6, Blazor Server).

I followed too this thread: [Blazor ProtectedSessionStorage object NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69881004/blazor-protectedsessionstorage-object-null), but when I try to set session data the code stop and immediately exit from his scope.

This is my code:

**SessionService.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;
...

    public class SessionService
    {
        private ProtectedSessionStorage _sessionStorage;

        public SessionService(ProtectedSessionStorage storage)
        {
            _sessionStorage = storage;
        }

        public async Task<User> GetUserProperty()
        {
            var value = await _sessionStorage.GetAsync<User>("user");
            return value.Value;
        }

        public async Task SetUserProperty(User value)
        {
            await _sessionStorage.SetAsync("user", value);
        }
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    //registering the service
    services.addScoped<SessionService>();
    ...
}
```

***MyComponent.razor***

```
@code
{
   [Inject] public SessionService SessionService { get; set; } = default!;

   protected override async void OnInitialized()
   {
       InitUser();
       LoadInterface();
   }

   protected async Task InitUser()
   {
      ...
      try
      {
          User user = new User("id", "location"); 
          //after this row, code exit from this scope
          await SessionService.SetUserProperty(user);

          //this part of code aren't read
          if(..)
          {
             //some other check
          }
          ...
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          //No exceptions caught
      }
      
   }
{
```

What I Wrong?

---

***Update:***

I forgot async on onInitialized method and now code don't stop and don't exit from his scope. But unfortunately I receive this error on browser console.

```
blazor.server.js:1 
        
       [2022-02-09T17:11:25.128Z] Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'MyProject.Models.Shared.User' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. The match can be case-insensitive.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_ConstructorParameterIncompleteBinding(Type parentType)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectWithParameterizedConstructorConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage.ProtectedBrowserStorage.Unprotect[TValue](String purpose, String protectedJson)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage.ProtectedBrowserStorage.GetAsync[TValue](String purpose, String key)
   at MyProject.Services.Dashboard.SessionService.GetUserProperty() in C:\Source\MyProject\Services\Dashboard\SessionService.cs:line 18
   at MyProject.Shared.DashHeaderMenu.OnInitialized() in C:\Source\MyProject\Shared\DashHeaderMenu.razor:line 128
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__127_0(Object state)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.ExecuteSynchronously(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c.<.cctor>b__23_0(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.ExecuteBackground(WorkItem item)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved!**

When you try to insert an object, like a custom class (in my case is User), you need add an empty constructor for serialize and put into the Protected Session Storage.

```
public class User
{
   public string name;
   public string surname;
   public int id;
   .....

   //required for serialization
   public User(){}

   //others constructor used
   public User(string name, string surname, ...)
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

So, for solve all my problems I inserted `async` to `OnInitialized()` and add a empty constructor to `User` class